# Workbench migration via ssh - how to set up a tunnel

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssh, workbench, ssh-tunnel

I try to migrate MSSQL (local machine) to MYSQL (Amazon Web Services) usin Workbench. I can connect to both databases. However when I migrate I get this error:

> Mysql connections through SSH are not supported in this version...

Well, I found this in documentation:

> A workaround is to set up an encrypted tunnel, and then treat the MySQL target as a standard TCP (unencrypted) connection.

But I don't know how to set up a tunnel. Does anyone can help?

Comment: Are you tunneling from the MS SQL Server to the AWS MySQL box? If so, are you using Putty?

Comment: I am on windows machine and yes, I tried putty. I can set up ssh connection in putty as well as in workbench. The problem is that Workbench requires tunnel, which I don't know how to set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, if I'm understanding this correctly, I think I'd prefer to set up a tunnel in Putty. I don't have a solid grasp of how MySQL Workbench works (I'm assuming its analogous to SSMS), but I have used maaany SSH tunnels in my day. Here are some basic instructions:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/putty-create-ssh-port-tunnel/

You'll want to create a local tunnel from any port you choose (although I'd go with the MySQL default 3306) to the destination of `127.0.0.1:3306`. Be sure to click add and save your session settings in Putty.

Open the SSH connection to the AWS machine. Try to connect to your MySQL instance through `127.0.0.1:3306`. This should allow you to pull from your local SQL Server and send data to your AWS instance (through the tunnel, `127.0.0.1:3306` of course).

Hope this helps. Let me know if this doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: I created a tunnel using your instructions. In putty I see in log that Local port 3306 forwarting to host:3306.However I cannot connect to mysql on AWS using Workbench (127.0.0.1:3306)..

Comment: Hm, not sure if that host:3306 part is right. Does your tunnels section in Putty look like this? http://i.imgur.com/rGFC0n7.png

Comment: No, by host I meant ec2 server public IP address.

Comment: That might be the issue. The destination has to be `127.0.0.1:3306`. A tunnel takes traffic from your local machine to the EC2 instance. When it gets to the EC2 instance, it goes to the destination IP and port. By saying `127.0.0.1:3306`, you're telling EC2 instance to send the traffic to 127.0.0.1, basically itself, on port 3306, the MySQL port.

Comment: You are right. I tried 127.0.0.1:3306 as destination - it works!
Now Workbench migrates like crazy. Thank you !

Comment: @MikeGorski You're welcome, always glad to help. Would you mind marking as answer if this answered your question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Amazon ec2:
On Windows machine connect using putty via ssh:

1. In session host name (user@public_ip_address)
2. Connection -> SSH -> Tunnels (Source port: 3306 OR choose free one) AND (Destination 127.0.0.1:3306)
3. You can check if tunnel was establihed in event log (right click on terminal bar)
4. In Workbench now you can use TCP/IP without SSH.

Thanks guys!